# Play Games Services testing for open beta testers

Tags: android, google-play-games

I have a published game in Google Play Game Service that links to a beta Android app. In Google Play Console I selected beta testing method as "Open Beta Testing". My problem is that the beta testers cannot sign in to Play Game. I tested with testers added to Play Game and it works fine. So it's not likely that I had integration mistake. I also enabled Alpha and Beta Tester groups under "Testing" of Play Game but no luck.
It seems that Play Game only supports Close Beta tester but not Open Beta testers. 
Can any one confirm this ?

Answer (score 0):

Been Googling around and found this [documentation of Best Practices](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/launch/beta-tests.html#best-practices). It was stated that,

> You can run a closed alpha and an open beta test on your app concurrently. If you run an open alpha test, you can't use the open or closed beta track. Keep in mind the [version code](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213#availability) rules when using different tracks.